# How to migrate data between 3 microservices

Tags: database, spring-boot, microservices, flyway

Let's imagine that I have 3 microservice:

1. The source service contains data in XML format inside the database.
2. The target service should contain transformed XML as a ZIP file.
3. The 3rd service knows how to transform XML to ZIP.

Currently, each microservice stores data into its own schema, but in the future, it could be separate databases per each microservice.

The task is to write flyway script or any other mechanism how to migrate data from source service to target service.

To migrate this data I have to create a strong dependency on service #3, it should start before service #1 or #2, but I can't guarantee that.

Do you know any good practices, tools or at least some ideas how to do that?

Comment: I don't know what means "target service should contain transformed XML" but you can maybe look at XSLT transformation. I think if you want some help you need to provide more informations.

Comment: transformed means - it should be splited on few files and folders and put all these things into zip archive